# Restore ADT (Android Development Tools) Perspective Eclipse

Tags: android, adt, eclipse-adt

I have closed all perspectives in my Eclipse Workspace by mistake.

How can I restore the default perspective used to develop Android application?

Comment: Tried _Window_ -> _Reset Perspective_

Comment: As I have closed the perspective there is none I can reset.. I should open a new perspective, but I don't know which is the one used by Android

Comment: found it is the Java perspective! Thanks for the Hint

Comment: Although, I did not quite give the final solution, happy to try and help. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADT uses the default Resource perspective.

To open it again just go to: Window -> Open Perspective -> Resources (default)

Answer (score 4):

Go to open perspective -> Java